# Making an Arduino library independent. (c/c++)

Tags: c++, linker, arduino

I'm currently working on a project which executes correctly using an arduino library (VirtualWire), yet would like to move away from Arduino and back into pure C/C++.

I could:

```
- rewrite the actual arduino functions
- rewrite the calls to arduino functions (change pinmode to DDRx, etc)
- use the arduino core source code in conjunction with the library.
```

I have already attempted the last point, moving the relevent arduino source code in with the virtual wire library, however when i try to compile- i cant link against the VirtualWire library.

NOTE: the VirtualWire library and its dependencies (hopefully) is located in the same directory as my source code (as a test).

Using the following compile command, i achieve the following errors:

```
avr-g++ -mmcu=atmega32u4 -Os -DF_CPU=8000000UL -IVirtualWire -LVirtualWire -lVirtualWire transmitter.cpp -o transmitter.o

c:/winavr-20100110/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.3/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lVirtualWire
```

Or alternatively,

```
avr-g++ -mmcu=atmega32u4 -Os -DF_CPU=8000000UL -IVirtualWire -LVirtualWire transmitter.cpp -o transmitter.o

C:\cygwin\tmp/cc8d5ab7.o: In function `setup':
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `vw_set_tx_pin'
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `vw_set_rx_pin'
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `vw_set_ptt_pin'
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `vw_set_ptt_inverted'
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `vw_setup'
C:\cygwin\tmp/cc8d5ab7.o: In function `main':
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `vw_send'
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `vw_wait_tx'
transmitter.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `delay'
```

And lastly,

```
avr-g++ -mmcu=atmega32u4 -Os -DF_CPU=8000000UL transmitter.cpp -o transmitter.o

transmitter.cpp:1:25: error: VirtualWire.h: No such file or directory
transmitter.cpp: In function 'int main()':
transmitter.cpp:26: error: 'HIGH' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:26: error: 'digitalWrite' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:27: error: 'uint8_t' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:27: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
transmitter.cpp:27: error: 'vw_send' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:28: error: 'vw_wait_tx' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:29: error: 'LOW' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:30: error: 'delay' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
transmitter.cpp:42: error: 'CLKPR' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:44: error: 'vw_set_tx_pin' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:45: error: 'vw_set_rx_pin' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:46: error: 'vw_set_ptt_pin' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:47: error: 'vw_set_ptt_inverted' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:48: error: 'vw_setup' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:49: error: 'OUTPUT' was not declared in this scope
transmitter.cpp:49: error: 'pinMode' was not declared in this scope
```

I am familiar with C/C++, however only today did i find out there were different types of libraries.

Is there something obvious i am doing wrong, or an easier way to transfer this library from Arduino to pure C/C++?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ld can't find the library file.  Adjust your linker parameters to make sure your library path includes the directory the library is in.

Comment: The VirtualWire library doesn't have a lib file, any chance you can explain what this means to me and how i should go about compiling without arduino?

(i now understand the -l flag looks for the lib file)

Comment: @Feyre: If it doesn't "come" with a pre-compiled `.lib`, build it yourself by source!

Comment: The library must have a file somewhere--it's not just a header file.  See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess for a basic description of the build process for an arduino.  Are you trying to deploy to a different platform?  You may find the library will not work even if you recompile, but you will need to compile the library either way if you don't have a linkable copy.  I am unclear what you mean by moving "away from arduino."

Comment: There is no language C/C++! You are using C++ (unfavourable choice for an ATMega - but your project, your decission), so do not add C tags!

Comment: c++1X is nice for atmega

Comment: @KemyLand: I'm unsure how, but will definitely check it out!

Comment: @TomW: Ill read up on that now, but from what i can see, the library consists only (excluding examples, and docs) two headers and one source file. I'm looking to get the code working on the Teensy (2.0) microcontroller. 
By "moving away from arduino" i really just want to work from a text editor and command line as opposed the Arduino's GUI interface- and would prefer to have the library not dependent on arduino.

Comment: @Olaf: We are yet to decide which of the two languages, but my test yes, is written in c++, yet i agree that c++ is unfavorable, yet the library in question is written (or saved as cpp) c++.